# Mysterious " " in Swift 4 print output (Xcode 9Beta)

Tags: swift

I believe this is my first post here. I am teaching myself Swift and have come across some odd behavior involving the mysterious appearance of a leading " " in a print statement. I was exploring print formatting and this code is producing a leading " " in the first dashedLine printed.
Code:

```
var dashedLine      = "-------------------------------------------------------------------"
print("a bunch of text\n", dashedLine)
print(dashedLine)
```

Output:

```
a bunch of text    
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why the leading space before the first dashed line?
I've read the Swift 4 documentation. (In playing with "terminator" syntax at the end of a print list, I get unanticipated results, including suppression of output, depending.) I am curious as to the appearance of the leading space as my primary question.

Comment: code:var dashedLine      = "-------------------------------------------------------------------"
average = Double(sum / counter)
print("a bunch of text\n")
print(dashedLine)

Comment: Welcome to SO! @DavidPasztor edited your question as I was also - he added four spaces to each line of code to make it appear as code. Just thought you'd like to know.

Comment: thanks David for properly formatting my 1st post...!

Answer (score 1):

By default, a print statement with multiple arguments prints those out with a space in between.

You can find more in Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print).

Answer (score 1):

Following on to @bajracharyas353’s answer, a solution if you’re needing to avoid this would be to combine strings using any of the methods Swift allows, like `"a" + "b"` or `String.append`, or `print(String1, String2, separator: "")`.

As for suppression of output, I think I’ve run into the same thing with JWTs. There seems to be a pretty modest limit on output, but I could be wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

The `Swift.print(_ items: Any...)` function prints multiple arguments separated by a space.

## Solution

Use `print("a bunch of text\n", dashedLine, separator: "")` instead